# Getting elements from SOAP Header with cxf-interceptor in MULE CE 3.3.0

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, mule, interceptor

I want to Getting elements from SOAP Header in MULE CE 3.3.0.
In flow I set WSDLLocation and my custom java class.

This is my flow code that I copied them below:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="9095" 
    path="MuleLog/Service" exchange-pattern="request-response">
<custom-processor class="com.example.processors.SOAPHeaderExtractor" /> 
    <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"
        namespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" service="Weather" >
        <cxf:inInterceptors  >
            <spring:bean id="inLogger" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />   
        </cxf:inInterceptors>   
    </cxf:proxy-service>        
</http:inbound-endpoint>

 <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx">
 </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

and this is my SOAPHeaderExtractor class:

---

```
        package com.example.processors;


    import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
    import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

    import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
    import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
    import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;

    public class SOAPHeaderExtractor implements MessageProcessor {

        @Override
        public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) {     
            try
            {
                MuleMessage inputMessage =  event.getMessage(); 
                SOAPMessage soapMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, 
                        new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(inputMessage.getPayloadAsString().getBytes()));
                 SOAPHeader header = soapMsg.getSOAPHeader();            
                 System.out.println(header.getElementsByTagName("sampler").item(0).getTextContent() );
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }       
            return event ;
        }
    }
```

---

- but when I run it and enter the address `http://localhost:9095/MuleLog/Service?wsdl`. I saw these errors in MULE console.

### ERRORs in MULE Ce 3.3.0, I  see these errors after that I entered the adress in browser?*

```
        Apr 13, 2013 11:16:50 AM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory createEnvelope
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPHeader(MessageImpl.java:1261)
    at com.example.processors.SOAPHeaderExtractor.process(SOAPHeaderExtractor.java:23)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:192)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:174)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:153)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:310)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:305)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:304)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:250)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:163)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    ... 58 more

CAUSE:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPHeader(MessageImpl.java:1261)
    at com.example.processors.SOAPHeaderExtractor.process(SOAPHeaderExtractor.java:23)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:192)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:174)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:153)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:310)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:305)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:304)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:250)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:163)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    ... 58 more
---------
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPHeader(MessageImpl.java:1261)
    at com.example.processors.SOAPHeaderExtractor.process(SOAPHeaderExtractor.java:23)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:192)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:174)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:153)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:310)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:305)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:304)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:250)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:163)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

CAUSE:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getSOAPHeader(MessageImpl.java:1261)
    at com.example.processors.SOAPHeaderExtractor.process(SOAPHeaderExtractor.java:23)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:85)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:29)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform any kind of operation over a Soap related payload the best option is usually using a cxf interceptor.

As an example you can refer to the class [MuleHeadersInInterceptor](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.3.0/modules/cxf/src/main/java/org/mule/module/cxf/support/MuleHeadersInInterceptor.java)

Comment: can you help me more? I have a clear sample of using CXF-Interceptor (java class + Configuration XML file).

Comment: The class i've provided you add soap headers, tweaking it to make it read the header already present shouldn't be too hard

Comment: how about my configuration XML that I copied at the top of this page. Is it correct? or I have to change it?

Comment: The configuration is correct, you just have to remove the custom message processor and create instead a custom cxf interceptor (inspired to the MuleHeadersInInterceptor) and add it as a <cxf:inInterceptors />.

Comment: Can I use directly MuleHeadersInInterceptor class, without any changes? Or I have to make changes on it?

Comment: That class only adds the mule related headers. I believe your goal is slightly different, isn't it?

Comment: exactly I want to implement this idea  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987466/ip-addresses-log-file-by-all-requests-in-mule-ce-3-3-0 based on these descriptions in this link,Can I use this class? Or I have to use another things?

Comment: this is my main question that I asked it in stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987466/ip-addresses-log-file-by-all-requests-in-mule-ce-3-3-0 I explained my goal on it.

Comment: No, the MuleHeadersInInterceptor is only an example of an interceptor that uses cxf headers, you still need to implement your custom business logic

Comment: ,It means: I have to write my own java class and then I use it? Can you explain more about it? Thanks