# IP-addresses Log file by all requests in MULE CE 3.3.0?

Tags: web-services, cxf, mule, interceptor

in MULE CE 3.3.0 I want to implement this process:

[image]

1-  Post- office has a service for giving postal-code to clients. So post-office creates a WSDL-file for its service.

2-  Here, our company is a connector between post-office and clients. Our company using mule and create another WSDL file based on post-office’s WSDL file and published out the WSDL for client usage.

3-  Company-A and Company-B, get the WSDL-file URL and for instance in My-eclipse IDE or any other IDEs create a portlet and deploy it in a liferay portal as a web-service for displaying postal-code to its clients.

During this process I want to have a log file of ip-addresses. It means, I want to after each request that Company-A’s client or Company-B’s client sent to the server(Our company), it’s Ip-address insert into a database or in a file.

I illustrated my position in the image by a red Arrow. Now I want to put an script in MULE server that and gather all the ip addresses that Company-A's and Company-B's customers who use post-code webservice.

Can I use **cxf-interceptor**  for this issuse ? and how? guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As genjosanzo has suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15993127/387927, you can access all the Mule headers in a CXF interceptor. This means that yes, you can achieve your goal with a CXF interceptor.

Here is an example of such an interceptor: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.3.1/modules/cxf/src/main/java/org/mule/module/cxf/support/MuleHeadersInInterceptor.java

Here is a configuration sample that shows how to use Spring to instantiate and configure CXF interceptors: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.3.1/modules/cxf/src/test/resources/header-conf.xml

The gist of it is:

```
<cxf:inInterceptors>
    <spring:bean id="foo1" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
</cxf:inInterceptors>
```